# No Module named pyspark_cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-2.0

I am trying to access a Cassandra database through Spark. For that I am using the code below:

```
pyspark --packages TargetHolding:pyspark-cassandra:0.3.5

import pyspark_cassandra
```

Then I get the following error:

```
No Module named pyspark_cassandra
```

Any ideas to what causes this?

Comment: You need to explain more about how you have Cassandra configured. There is a pyspark_cassandra github repo. Have you configured pyspark? If you're using DSE there are better ways to enable Spark in the /etc/default/dse script. I can't provide an answer without additional configuration details. Edit your Question and add more config details.

Comment: @p-k-lenka, have you got any solution on this?